# Good study material for C#,JavaScript,PHP?

Tags: c#, php, javascript

I am a proficient C++/Qt coder, having worked only on desktop projects till now. I wanted to extend my knowledge base into the web realm. In this regard, can some of you suggest good reading material for C#,JavaScript and php? And are there any standards for these languages as there are for C,C++ like ANSI C,C99,C++0x etc.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, I would recommend these three books whose approach to PHP Web development 
is quite disciplined and could actually be used to build small- medium (perhaps large) 
scale projects. They are not really meant for beginners but with your good 
background in C++ / O-O programming, it should be relatively easy to pick the material.

1. [Beginning PHP and MySQL Ecommerce from Novice To Professional](http://www.amazon.ca/Beginning-PHP-MySQL-E-Commerce-Professional/dp/1590598644)
2. [PHP Anthology : Object Oriented PHP Solutions][2]
3. [PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice][3]

Answer (score 0):

**C#**:

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598849)'s the book and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)'s the ECMA standard specification.

Answer (score 0):

While books on any topic are the ultimate things to read, you may want to try out [this tutorial](http://tizag.com/phpT) to start coding in PHP almost instantly.

That said, there is no substitute to reading a real book.

For javascript, I don't really know which book to pick first. I learnt javascript by writing javascript apps, and reading lots of articles and tutorials.

PS: I'm Qt Fan! I'm learning :D

Answer (score 0):

For C#

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/vcsharp/aa336768%28en-us%29.aspx)
- C# complete reference
- C# Bible

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, the website http://www.php.net/ is "The Best".
You go to manual
https://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php to get started.

What C/C++ developers should know about C#, use [.Net Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/).